# Where's the CSS Attribute?

Tags: css, wordpress

Newbie question: Can someone tell me what is governing the height of the menu with inspect element? (this is a wp template) Changing the padding on the ".li a {" makes the menu buttons smaller but I cant seem to vertically shrink the container..

Thanks for spotting it in advance!

Comment: A link would be helpful. Is there a reason you can't inspect it yoourself?

Comment: Have you used the height: xxpx; for the container?

Comment: Please, see the guides [ask] and http://sscce.org

Answer (score 0):

If the height property is not explicitly stated, it is inherited from one of its ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

If `.li a` contains the padding property with value 10px, then you must alter the values like

```
.li a {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; // Padding: top right bottom left
}
```

Thus we need to work with top and bottom values only.